# How to compare iterator value with an integer?

Tags: c++

The function `removeAll(vector<int>& v, const int& x)` intends to remove all elements that equals to `int x` except the first one.

For example

```
originally
v = [2,2,3,5,5,6,2,8,6] 

after removeAll(v, 2)
the output should be [2,3,5,5,6,8,6]
```

But my code seems fail to compare `if (*it == x)`, so does anyone know the reason? I didn't find any similar question online.

```
void removeAll(vector<int>& v, const int& x)
{
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it < v.end(); it++)
    {
        int count = 0;

        if (*it == x && count > 0)
        {
            v.erase(it);
        }
        
        if (*it == x)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `it < v.end()` doesn't look like a good idea.

Comment: `count` is local to the loop. it is only set once. And even there you have a bigger problem; you just don't know it yet.

Comment: `v.erase(it);` invalidates `it`. Why are you ignoring the return value of `erase`?

Comment: What you seem to want is basically [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) (but note that it basically requires the container to be sorted).

Comment: There's a reason that [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/) is not implemented that way, and that there's a standard idiom for erasing the removed elements in a separate step.

Comment: Is the vector being sorted a prerequisite? Can the vector be in any order?

Comment: @WernerHenze Thanks for telling me :) I did not know `erase()` would return a value, I feel sorry. Now I correct it.

Comment: @Casey No it is not sorted, it would contain random int elements. I've corrected the issue now. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems:

- `count` must be declared outside of the loop, otherwise it's reset to `0` on every iteration.
- `it` must be incremented only when you chose to not erase an element.
- When you do erase an element, the return value of `erase` should be assigned to `it`. (Failing to do so would formally cause UB, but in practice might not break anything, if you're using `std::vector`. It's not going to work with for most other containers though.)

Here's the fixed code:

```
void removeAll(vector<int>& v, const int& x)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it < v.end();)
    {
        if (*it == x)
        {
            count++;
        }

        if (*it == x && count > 1)
        {
            it = v.erase(it);
        }
        else
        {
            it++;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the same code with minor style improvements:

```
void removeAll(std::vector<int> &v, int x)
{
    std::size_t count = 0;
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it < v.end();)
    {
        if (*it == x && count++ != 0)
            it = v.erase(it);
        else 
            it++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that I am now understand! :)

Answer (score 3):

What you want is this:

```
void remove_duplicates_of(std::vector<int>& v, int value)
{
    auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), value);
    if (it != v.end())
        v.erase(std::remove(std::next(it), v.end(), value), v.end());
}
```

This finds the first instance of `value`, and if found, erases every subsequent instance starting at the iterator position immediately past the point of discovery.

Comment: This is what you'd use in a real-world program, yes, but knowing how to do it without standard algorithms is also important.

Answer (score 0):

When you erase an iterator, it gets invalidated. The best way of doing this is with standard algorithms as shown in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66400155/10147399). The thing is, removing elements from the middle of a vector is expensive. It shifts all the elements after that position by 1 element every time you call it. It's better to shift all the elements in a single iteration and then remove what remains at the end. Removing elements from the end is relatively cheap. Here's roughly how you can do it without standard algorithms:

```
void remove_duplicates_of(std::vector<int>& v, int x) {
  auto it = v.begin();
  auto last = v.end();

  while (it != last && *it != x) ++it;  // find the first one

  if (it == last) return;  // if we didn't find anything, return

  ++it;                                 // skip the first
  while (it != last && *it != x) ++it;  // find the second

  if (it == last) return;  // if we didn't find anything, return

  auto next = it;
  while (++it != last)  // shift all other elements to front
    if (*it != x) *next++ = *it;

  // remove the rest
  v.erase(next, last);
}
```